# Equality evaluation in associative containers (STL)

Tags: c++, stl

I'm aware that STL associative containers (and other containers being sorted I would guess) use the sorting criterion to test for equality.

The sorting criterion for containers defaults to st::less, so that would make the equality test for a container:

```
if (! (lhs < rhs || rhs < lhs))
```

or something similar.  I had a couple questions about this...

First of all, it seems like a strangely inefficient way to compare for equality - why does the STL do it like this?  I would have expected STL containers to just take an extra default parameter for equality instead.

My second question is more about the evaluation of the if statement above in general.  In C++, how much of that statement would be evaluated (lhs > rhs) was true?  Would it stop trying after evaluating the side that failed thus saving some efficiency?  If so, which part of the expression is evaluated first?

Comment: That's equivalence, not equality...

Comment: @K-ballo what's the difference?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In "Effective STL," Scott Meyers has an extensive discussion about this in **Item 19**:

> **Understand the difference between equality and equivalence.**

*Equality*, as you might expect, is based on `operator==`.

*Equivalence* "is based on the relative ordering of object values in a sorted range... Two objects have eqivalent values in a container `c` if neither precedes the other in `c`'s sort order."

Meyers expresses it this way:

```
!( w1 < w2 ) // it's not true that w1 < w2
&&           // and
!( w2 < w1 ) // it's not true that w2 < w1
```

Meyers then restates:

> This makes sense: two values are equivalent (with respect to some
>   ordering criterion) if neither precedes the other (according to that
>   criterion.)

As for why the STL does it this way:

> By using only a single comparison function and by employing
>   equivalence as the arbiter of what it means to be "the same," the
>   standard associative containers... avoid the kind of confusion that
>   would arise from mixing uses of equality and equivalence within
>   standard associative containers.

Read Item 19 (which spans the better part of 6 pages) for yourself to get the full flavor.

Comment: "_This makes sense: two values are equivalent (with respect to some ordering criterion) if neither precedes the other (according to that criterion.)_" No, **it makes sense because the requirement for using the sorted containers is that it makes sense**.

Comment: You're downvoting me for quoting Scott Meyers?

Comment: Exactly. "_This makes sense:_ ..." is meaningless and potentially misleading.

Comment: He's talking about why equivalence is expressed using `!(w1<w2) && !(w2<w1)`; his "This makes sense" statement refers to that.

Comment: @larsmans "_this makes perfect sense on its own_" It doesn't. "_"Each preorder induces an equivalence relation between elements,_" What is the preorder here???

Comment: @Gnawme "_He's talking about_" I know what he is talking about. His remark is trivial or meaningless, or wrong.

Comment: @curiousguy: never mind that comment. The [strict weak ordering requirement](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/SortedAssociativeContainer.html) (see also C++ standard, I can't quote it verse and chapter) gives rise to an equivalence relation on its own: those *x* and *y* for which neither *x* < *y* nor *y* < *x*, exactly what Meyers gives.

Comment: @larsmans "_see also C++ standard, I can't quote it verse and chapter_" don't mind the ISO standard, it's here: [Strict Weak Ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html): "_Invariants: Transitivity of equivalence: Equivalence (as defined above) is transitive: if `x` is equivalent to `y` and `y` is equivalent to `z`, then `x` is equivalent to `z`. (This implies that equivalence does in fact satisfy the mathematical definition of an equivalence relation.)_"

Comment: "_gives rise to an equivalence relation on its own: those x and y for which neither x < y nor y < x, exactly what Meyers gives._" That there is an equivalence relation is an "invariant" of the Strict Weak Ordering concept, IOW a precondition of the use of sorted associative containers. When Meyer states that it "makes sense", he is just restating a fundamental requirement. It is an obvious requirement because **the sorted containers need a total order on element values**. Meyer just makes the issue look than obvious than it really is. All this stuff merely hides the total order requirement.

Answer (score 5):

> STL associative containers

You mean: standard C++ sorted associative containers.

> I would have expected STL containers to just take an extra default parameter for equality instead.

What would that achieve? In your textbook red-black tree algorithm, instead of

```
if (x < y)
    // ...
else if (y < x)
    // ...
else
    // equality
```

you'd have

```
if (x == y)
    // equality
else if (x < y)
    // ...
else
    // y < x
```

so still two comparisons in the worst case.

Responding to the comments to this answer: having only a less-than operator to supply makes the containers substantially easier to use, since there's no need to maintain consistency between less-than and equals. Let's imagine you have a program storing floating point numbers. One day, someone decides to replace the bitwise-equality `float_equals` function, that just happened to be used by some container *but also by their code*, by an approximate comparison. If that person doesn't update the `float_less` function, because *their code doesn't use that function*, then your container code mysteriously breaks.

(Oh and in the example code shown, short-circuiting applies, as always.)

Comment: And this eliminates subtle bugs that might arise if the less-than and equality operators didn't agree 100%.

Comment: "_this eliminates subtle bugs that might arise if the less-than and equality operators didn't agree 100%._" and it creates subtle bugs if the less-than operator doesn't agree with itself. ;)

Comment: @MarkRansom: very true, added that to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the second question: Standard C lazy evaluation rules for boolean expressions apply. If the LHS of `||` is true, the RHS is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

C++ evaluates if() left to right for your case with ||. Evaluates left side (lhs < rhs) - If it's true and it's not a compound statement (it's not in your case), it evaluates the whole if as true without checking the right side. (Then indeed returns negated value since there's not in front of it.) If it's false then it moves on to the right side (rhs < lhs) and evaluates that and then the whole expression.

Comment: "_C++ evaluates if() left to right._" Wrong. Only `a && b`, `a || b`, `a, b`, `a ? b : c` are evaluated left-to-right.

Comment: You're incorrect fine sir. a ? b : c is evaluated right to left. Also, i was referring to his <code>||</code> which is indeed evaluated in left side then right side manner.

Comment: "_You're incorrect fine sir. a ? b : c is evaluated right to left_" What do you mean? In which order are a, b, and c evaluated according to you? "_i was referring to his <code>||</code> which is indeed evaluated in left side then right side manner._" in a potentially _very_ misleading way.

Comment: ScarletAmaranth, you have the right to admit that you were wrong.

Answer (score -2):

> First of all, it seems like a strangely inefficient way to compare for equality

Yes, but sorted containers do this test relatively rarely.

Using a compare function like `strcmp` would be better. Using both less-than and compare would be still better.

> In C++, how much of that statement would be evaluated (lhs > rhs) was true?

In C and in C++, `a && b`, `a || b`, `a, b`, `a ? b : c` are evaluated left-to-right, with only the useful right part evaluated (except for **overloaded** `&&`, `||`, `,` operators in C++).

This allows several useful short tests like: `p != NULL && *p > 2`